# Counting population without using for-loop (using pipe or other method)

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe

I am trying to avoid for-loops as much as I can. The datasets are chunky and they look like:

**List A:**

```
Item Store  Date     Price  Description
x011  A     2017/09/01   10     Great
x011  A     2017/08/08   12     Soso
x011  B     2018/12/17   9.5    OK
x011  B     2019/02/27   9.5    OK
x012  A     2016/12/08   120    NA
x012  A     2017/10/12   120    NA
x012  B     2017/05/14   108    ...
x012  B     2018/04/08   108    ...
x012  C     2019/01/30   118    ...
x012  C     2019/12/30   118    ...
```

**List B**

```
Store  Date        Price  Description
A     2015/04/11   12     Soso
A     2016/12/08   12     Awsome
A     2017/08/08   12     Soso
A     2017/08/23   12     Awsome
A     2017/09/01   10     Great
A     2017/10/12   12     great
A     2018/11/14   12     Soso
B     2012/02/22   9.5    OK
B     2014/01/28   9.5    OK
B     2017/05/14   9.5    OK
B     2018/01/28   9.5    OK
B     2018/04/08   9.5    OK
B     2018/12/17   9.5    OK
B     2019/02/27   9.5    OK
B     2019/09/30   9.5    OK
C     2016/12/08   120    NA
C     2019/01/30   118    ...
C     2019/07/11   108    ...
C     2019/12/14   108    ...
C     2019/12/30   108    ...
C     2020/01/14   108    ...
```

I would like to find the final list like this (note: the total store population has to be counted between the date range for each item, as shown below in the Mid-way table) :

**Mid-way table**

```
Item  Store  StorePopulation   MinDate      MaxDate
x001  A      3                 2017/08/08   2017/09/01
x001  B      2                 2018/12/17   2019/02/27
x002  A      5                 2016/12/08   2017/10/12
x002  B      3                 2017/05/14   2018/04/08
x002  C      4                 2019/01/30   2019/12/30
```

**Final Table**

```
Item StoreType  StorePopulation   
x011  2          5
x012  3          12
```

I would like to know if there's a way that I can get the final table without using for-loop in R especially the original data is very chunky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do a non-equi join after converting the 'Date' columns to `Date` class

```
library(data.table)
#  convert the Date columns in each dataset to Date class
setDT(df1)[, Date := as.IDate(Date, "%Y/%m/%d")]  
setDT(df2)[, Date := as.IDate(Date, "%Y/%m/%d")]
# get the min and max  Date for each Item, Store
tmp <- df1[, .(MinDate = min(Date), MaxDate = max(Date)), .(Item, Store)]
# Do a non-equi join based on the Dates and Store
# get the frequency count (.N)
# Grouped by Item get the sum of StorePopulation 
# and number of unique elements in Store (uniqueN)
df2[tmp, .(StorePopulation = .N, Item),
     on = .(Store, Date >= MinDate, Date <= MaxDate),
    by = .EACHI][,.(StoreType =uniqueN(Store), 
      StorePopulation = sum(StorePopulation)) , .(Item)]
#   Item StoreType StorePopulation
#1: x011         2               5
#2: x012         3              12
```

---

Or with `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(lubridate)
df2 %>%
    mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) %>%
    fuzzy_left_join(
          df1 %>%
             mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) %>%
             group_by(Item, Store) %>%
             summarise(MinDate = min(Date), MaxDate = max(Date)) , 
                 by = c('Store', 'Date' = 'MinDate', 'Date' = 'MaxDate'),
                 match_fun = list(`==`, `>=`, `<=`)) %>%
    filter(!is.na(Store.y)) %>% 
    group_by(Item) %>%
    summarise(StoreType = n_distinct(Store.y), StorePopulation = n())
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  Item  StoreType StorePopulation
#  <chr>     <int>           <int>
#1 x011          2               5
#2 x012          3              12
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Item = c("x011", "x011", "x011", "x011", "x012", 
"x012", "x012", "x012", "x012", "x012"), Store = c("A", "A", 
"B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), Date = c("2017/09/01", 
"2017/08/08", "2018/12/17", "2019/02/27", "2016/12/08", "2017/10/12", 
"2017/05/14", "2018/04/08", "2019/01/30", "2019/12/30"), Price = c(10, 
12, 9.5, 9.5, 120, 120, 108, 108, 118, 118), Description = c("Great", 
"Soso", "OK", "OK", NA, NA, "...", "...", "...", "...")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

df2 <- structure(list(Store = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"
), Date = c("2015/04/11", "2016/12/08", "2017/08/08", "2017/08/23", 
"2017/09/01", "2017/10/12", "2018/11/14", "2012/02/22", "2014/01/28", 
"2017/05/14", "2018/01/28", "2018/04/08", "2018/12/17", "2019/02/27", 
"2019/09/30", "2016/12/08", "2019/01/30", "2019/07/11", "2019/12/14", 
"2019/12/30", "2020/01/14"), Price = c(12, 12, 12, 12, 10, 12, 
12, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 120, 118, 108, 108, 
108, 108), Description = c("Soso", "Awsome", "Soso", "Awsome", 
"Great", "great", "Soso", "OK", "OK", "OK", "OK", "OK", "OK", 
"OK", "OK", NA, "...", "...", "...", "...", "...")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a brilliant method! :)

Comment: I like the fuzzy join idea, especially it inspires me a lot of things to modify my code. Thank you again :)

Comment: @mimibao1009 glad to know that it is useful for you. thanks